# how to write rspec for method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec2

I have following code in programmability folder

```
module Programmability
  module Parameter
    class Input < Parameter::Base
      attr_reader :args

  def initialize(name, type, **args)
    super(name, type)
    @args = args
  end

  def value=(val)
    if val
      val = convert_true_false(val)
--- some code ----
    end
    @value = val
  end      


  def convert_true_false(val)
    return val unless @args[:limit] == 1
    if [:char].include?(@type) && val == 'true'
      'Y'
    elsif [:char].include?(@type) && val == 'false'
      'N'
    elsif [:bit].include?(@type) && val == 'true'
      1
    elsif [:bit].include?(@type) && val == 'false'
      0
    end
  end
end
  end
end
```

I am trying to write rspec for method convert_true_false. I am new to rspec. any help is appreciated.

I tried doing this

```
   context 'returns Y if passed true'
    input = Programmability::Parameter::Input.new(name, type, limit)

      it 'returns Y' do
        name = 'unregister_series'
        type = ':char'
        limit = 1

        expect(input.value = 'true' ).to eq('Y')
      end
  end
```

but its not picking up limit value. when it reaches convert_true_false method it comes out of it since @args[:limit] is nil

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes updated question

Comment: Can you add the code in your spec that created the `input`?

Comment: sorry missed that. added

Comment: `args` are keyword arguments. Hence you should do `Input.new(name, type, limit: limit)`. It shouldn't let you create the object at all.

Comment: yeah you are right. let me try your solution

Comment: @ndn They're not keyword arguments, they're hash values. There's an explicit difference.

Comment: @DaveNewton, they are kwargs (variable length keyword arguments).

Comment: function convert_true_false wont return val = 'Y'. any idea whats wrong? i put byebug and i get (byebug) @args[:limit]
1
(byebug) @type
":char" (byebug) val
"true"

Comment: @User7354632781, for starters, what did it return. Print that. Also print the result of calling `convert_true_false`.

Comment: @ndn I guess, although I don't see much of a practical difference--you get a hash back.

Comment: I see convert_true_false is returning Y by putting byebug but test case failing       expected: "Y" got: "true" is expect(input.value = 'true' ).to eq('Y') wrong?

Comment: @DaveNewton, there are many differences, too long for a single comment. I'm sure you can find an article on the subject or already know some of them. But it's important to make the conceptual difference as well. I find the legacy alternative of hash as last parameter almost working as kwargs that we had before Ruby 2.0 as one of the downfalls of the language.

Comment: @User7354632781, added an answer.

Comment: @ndn I didn't; it was a simple workaround for a missing language feature. ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: Can you directly assign it? `@value = convert_true_false (val)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that setters always return the value passed:

```
class Test
  def foo=(foo)
    @foo = foo + 100
    return 42
  end
end

puts (Test.new.foo = 69) # 69
```

To resolve it, simply check the value after you assigned it:

```
# instead of
expect(input.value = 'true').to eq 'Y'

# do
input.value = 'true'
expect(input.value).to eq 'Y'
```

Comment: input returns <Programmability::Parameter::Input:0x007f99573785a0 @name="unregister_series", @type=:char, @args={:limit=>1}, @value="Y" so i did expect(input.value).to eq('Y') but getting error        expected: "Y"
            got: "N'Y'"